# Disable Input text field on checkbox status

Tags: javascript, html

I already have implemented this but the issue is i also have a select all checkbox. when i check that box, all the boxes gets selected. But the disabled input fields are not enabled. When i manually tick each box, it works.

Here is my code for select all:

```
HTML:
        <label class="fancy-checkbox element-left">
                        <input type="checkbox" onClick="toggleLinen(this)">
                        <span>Select All / Un-select All</span>
                    </label>

JS:
        function toggleLinen(source) {
            checkboxes = document.getElementsByClassName('workrequest');
            for(var i=0, n=checkboxes.length;i<n;i++) {
                checkboxes[i].checked = source.checked;
            }
        }
```

Here is my input box enable script. By default the input text field is disabled:

```
HTML:
        <div class="containerforitems">
                        <label class="fancy-checkbox element-left">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="workrequest checkboxcustom" name="btowel" id="btowel" {{ old('btowel') ? 'checked' : '' }}>
                            <span>Bath Towel</span>
                        </label>
                        <input type="number" min="0" class="workrequest amtcustom" name="btowelamt" id="btowelamt" value="{{ old('btowelamt') }}" disabled>
                    </div>

JS:
        document.getElementById('ftowel').onchange = function() {
    document.getElementById('ftowelamt').disabled = !this.checked;
};
```

Like i mentioned, when i do a select all, it does not enable the text field. But when i tick it manually, it works.

Comment: As said in the original answer, use `setAttribute` & `removeAttribute`.

Comment: @Tushar i dont see how it is a duplicate. I am fairly new to JS

Comment: If you look at the question, it is exactly same as yours. Did you try to use `setAttribute` & `removeAttribute` as shown in the answer?

Comment: yes it does not help. My current code works. The only difference is that is does not work when i click select all.

Comment: You'd rather create a create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example and put it in a snippet. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve